# Core Plot library to draw graph in auto layout Xcode 6.1 for any device orientation, legends in iOS

Tags: ios, core-plot

I want to draw graph in iOS native app (Making app using auto layout and Xcode 6.1)..after googling I found core plot lib for drawing graph. 
I am struggling with this library to do make pie,bar,donut and line chart as I want.
I used the examples which are in 'examples' folder of this library.

1. How do I make graph to adjust when app is rotating and takes auto
   layout constraints?
2. For bar/line chart-I don't get idea to make graph compact or make
   scroll when there is large data to show on x or y axis?
3. For any chart- How do I show legends(title or explanation for
   graph)?
4. How do I show values on bar/pie/line itself(Value on each
       pie slice / every bar/ every line point)?
5. Can I set X and Y axis start and end point?

Please help if anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The *Plot Gallery* example app demonstrates all of these things. You'll need to use the latest code from GitHub (release 1.5.1 doesn't have some of the newer features like auto layout; 1.6 will be out soon, but isn't quite ready yet).

1. The iOS version of the *Plot Gallery* uses a storyboard and auto layout to control the UI.
2. Set `allowsUserInteraction` to `YES` on the plot space to enable pinch zoom and scrolling behavior. You can disable pinch gestures and keep the scrolling behavior with the `allowPinchScaling` property on the hosting view.
3. Many of the *Plot Gallery* demos have legends. Look for `CPTLegend` in the code. Ask a more specific question if you need more help with this.
4. These are known as "data labels" in Core Plot. Many of the *Plot Gallery* demos have them. You can set a formatter and text style on the plot to turn them on, or use a plot delegate to have more control over each label.
5. Set the `xRange` and/or `yRange` of the plot space associated with the axes to control the coordinate space of the plot area.